# SQL wildcard Oddities, need stricter results

Tags: mysql, wildcard

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE list_item LIKE "%_1375_%"
```

returns results it should not. For example a result with *13753* in the list_item instead of *1375*, even though the 3 comes before the underscore.

```
 _13753_  and _1375_ are written above and not suppose to be italic.
```

Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Can you try [_]  and see if that solves the problem? i.e. wrap _ in []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL reference manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use “_” to match any single
>   character and “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters
>   (including zero characters).

So, you'll have to escape them to match a literal underscore character.  Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM list
WHERE list_item LIKE "%\_1375\_%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore means any character. Are you looking for values with an underscore? In that case you need to escape it

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE list_item LIKE "%\_1375\_%"
```

Comment: Open up mysql console and run the commands that follow, it returns both records, just like you'd expect:   create database foo;
use foo;
create table list (id int auto_increment primary key, list_item varchar(50) not null);insert into list (list_item) values ("Hello _1375_ Hello"); insert into list (list_item) values ("1234_1375_4321");  SELECT * FROM list WHERE list_item LIKE "%\_1375\_%";

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
LIKE '%[_]1375[_]%'
```